# How do I validate innerText for a SharePoint multiline form field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

Here is the code snipper for my problem:

```
var field1 = $("div[id='Owner_fdcd6919-2ee0-4200-90b4-32f6cd3d757e_$TextField_inplacerte']");
console.log(field1[0].innerText);
if(field1[0].innerText.length < 1){
    alert('Please fill out Column B');
    field1.attr("style", "border: solid 1px #ff4c42 !important");
    return false;
}
```

What's weird is the output from `console.log(field1[0].innerText);` is always correct, however when I try to validate the innerText in the if statement, it results in false every time (I don't see the alert).

I've tried different types of string validation as well (such as `if (!field1[0].innerText.toString())`) but nothing works.

All help appreciated.

Edit: There appears to be some HTML that gets formatted into the string even though nothing is outputted to the console.

The text is being extracted between `<p></p>`. I've spent 3 hours trying every conceivable way to make the string empty, I'm done with this. Goodluck to anyone who has the same problem...

```
<p>​

<span id="ms-rterangepaste-start" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span id="ms-rterangecursor-start" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span id="ms-rterangecursor-end" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Have you tried trimming the innerText with `.trim()` before the comparison?  If there is whitespace that gives it a length, it would fail the conditional.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my edit, it turned out there were some weird span elements getting included in the JavaScript. My final solution was just to change the fields from RichText to PlainText.